# How did MailChimp get past 2000 like requirement for custom tabs?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a similar platform to MailChimp and we want to create the same kind of integration. The integration creates custom tab and MC integration can be used on every page, even if your page only has 1 like, you can use it with no problems. Overall FB has  a new policy that only pages with at least 2000 likes can create and use custom tab apps.

Did they have some special agreement to get past this or do you have to be partner or anything else?
It would be great to know if there are some ways to get past the requirement just as MC.

Comment: They probably have a special agreement with Facebook. There is little chance that you get the same, as a "normal" app developer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that is what I also think, as there is no information about how to apply for it and if there was, everyone would.